# getting total value after entering the values in the form and inserting into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If i select Local Sales from dorpdown and enter DEF, GHI values then the sum of DEF,GHI should be displayed in total value or if i select Inter State,Stock Transfers from dropdown then if we enter ABC value that value should be displayed in total value or else if we select JOB WORK,EXEMPTED SALES from dropdown then the total value should be displayed as zero. The total value which ever we are getting that should be inserted into database.

Controller:

```
function addinvoice()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user','User');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('freight_charges');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('abc');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('def');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ghi');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('total');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {       
    $data['mainpage']='invoice';
    $data['mode']='add';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this -> invoice_model -> insert();
        $this->flash->success('<h2> Details added Successfully!</h2>');
        redirect('invoice');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function insert()
{
$data['total']=0;
$data['user'] = $this->input->post('user');
$data['ghi'] = ($this->input->post('ghi'))?$this->input->post('ghi'):0;
$data['abc'] = ($this->input->post('abc'))?$this->input->post('abc'):0;
$data['def'] = ($this->input->post('def'))?$this->input->post('def'):0;
$data['total'] = $data['ghi'] + $data['abc'] + $data['def'];
$data['freight_charges'] = $this->input->post('freight_charges');
$this->db->insert('invoice',$data);
}
```

View:

```
<script>
function showRequiredOption(cval)
{
if((cval=='interstate') || (cval == "stocktransfers"))
{
    $('#ghi').hide();
    $('#def').hide();
    $('#abc').show();
}
else if ((cval=='exemptedsales') || (cval=="zeroratedsales") ||(cval=="jobwork"))
{
    $('#ghi').hide();
    $('#def').hide();
    $('#abc').hide();

}
else
{
    $('#abc').hide();
    $('#ghi').show();
    $('#def').show();

}
}
</script>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
<div id="legend">
<legend class="">Profile Information</legend>
</div>  
<form role="form" action="<?php echo site_url();?>invoice/addinvoice" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="location" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">     
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="user">User</label> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <select id="user" name="user" onchange="showRequiredOption(this.value)">
            <option value="employee">Local Sales</option>
            <option value="interstate">Inter state</option>
            <option value="stocktransfers">Stock transfers</option>
            <option value="exemptedsales">Exempted Sales</option>
            <option value="zeroratedcompany">Zero Rated Sales</option>
            <option value="jobwork">Job Work</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>      
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="freight_charges">Freight Charges</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="freight_charges" name="freight_charges" value="<?php echo set_value('freight_charges');?>"  />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="abc" style="display:none;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="abc">ABC</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="abc" name="abc" value="<?php echo set_value('abc');?>"/ >
  </div>
</div>  
 <div class="form-group" id="def">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="def">DEF </label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="def" name="def" value="<?php echo set_value('def');?>"/ >
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group" id="ghi">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="ghi">GHI</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ghi" name="ghi" value="<?php echo set_value('ghi');?>"/  >
  </div>
</div> 
  <div class="form-group" id="cgst">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="total">Total</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="total"   >
  </div>
</div>      
 <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Whatever values i have selected from dropdown only those values to be inserted into database and the rest of the values should be inserted as zero in the database.

Actually i am not getting how to do these can anyone check this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For this **the rest of the values should be inserted as zero in the database** set database as default value to Zero.

Comment: any one please help me these out thanks in advance

Comment: Edited my code given by @K.Uzair it is adding the sum and inserting the total amount value in database.once we enter abc,def,ghi values it should show the sum value in total column but it is not showing in total column it is inserting in database.But here i need to show the total value in column then i will submit the data.

Comment: Can any one please sort out these problem thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying total amount on enter the details.

```
<script>
function showRequiredOption(cval)
{
if((cval=='interstate') || (cval == "stocktransfers"))
{
$('#ghi').hide();
$('#def').hide();
$('#abc').show();
}
else if ((cval=='exemptedsales') || (cval=="zeroratedsales") ||   (cval=="jobwork"))
{
$('#ghi').hide();
$('#def').hide();
$('#abc').hide();
}
else
{
$('#abc').hide();
$('#ghi').show();
$('#def').show();
}
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
//handler to trigger sum event
$(".txt").each(function() {

  $(this).keyup(function(){
    calculateSum();
  });
});

});

function calculateSum() {
var sum = 0;
//iterate through each textboxes and add the values
$(".txt").each(function() {
  //add only if the value is number
  if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
  }
  });
//.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  }
  </script>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
  <div id="legend">
  <legend class="">Profile Information</legend>
  </div>  
  <form role="form" action="<?php echo site_url();?>invoice/addinvoice" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="location" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">     
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="user">User</label> 
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <select id="user" name="user" onchange="showRequiredOption(this.value)">
        <option value="employee">Local Sales</option>
        <option value="interstate">Inter state</option>
        <option value="stocktransfers">Stock transfers</option>
        <option value="exemptedsales">Exempted Sales</option>
        <option value="zeroratedcompany">Zero Rated Sales</option>
        <option value="jobwork">Job Work</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   </div>      
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="freight_charges">Freight Charges</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control txt" id="freight_charges" name="freight_charges" value="<?php echo set_value('freight_charges');?>"  />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="abc" style="display:none;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="abc">ABC</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control txt" id="abc" name="abc" value="<?php echo set_value('abc');?>"/ >
  </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group" id="def">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="def">DEF </label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control txt" id="def" name="def" value="<?php echo set_value('def');?>"/ >
  </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group" id="ghi">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="ghi">GHI</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control txt" id="ghi" name="ghi" value="<?php echo set_value('ghi');?>"/  >
  </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group" id="summation">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="total">Total</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
  <span id="sum" class="form-control" type="text" name="total">0</span>
  </div>
  </div>      
  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check for posted values in your php code as:

```
$total = 0;
if($this->input->post('this')){
     $total = $this->input->post('this');//value in total
}
if($this->input->post('this2')){
     $total += $this->input->post('this2');//value in total
}
```

and at the end send $total value in db as well.
in short php if else tags you can set variables like;

```
$this = ($this->input->post('this'))?$this->input->post('this'):0;
$this2 = ($this->input->post('this2'))?$this->input->post('this2'):0;
```

and then at the end you can make total of them and save them to database. OR as suggested above in comments that make your columns as DEFAULT 0 in your table.

------- IN YOUR CASE------

```
function insert()
{
    $data['total']=0;
    $data['user'] = $this->input->post('user');
    $data['ghi'] = ($this->input->post('ghi'))?$this->input->post('ghi'):0;
    $data['abc'] = ($this->input->post('abc'))?$this->input->post('abc'):0;
    $data['def'] = ($this->input->post('def'))?$this->input->post('def'):0;
    $data['total'] = $data['ghi'] + $data['abc'] + $data['def'];
    $data['freight_charges'] = $this->input->post('freight_charges');
    $this->db->insert('invoice',$data);
}
```

---------------IN JavaScript------------
on your event handler you can sum these by their IDs.

```
var total = parseInt($('#ghi').val())+parseInt($('#def').val());
```

and then show this total in your total div

```
$('#yourTotalDiv').text(total);
```

Comment: Not getting what you have written can you please edit it in my code so that it will be easy for me to understand.

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam is there any issue in adding spaces between abc -> xyz ?

Comment: @ImranQamer trying is gives you results.

Comment: BTW i am using CI 3 and there is no error for me in this syntax, thats wh i am asking , may be i could not get any info regarding this.

Comment: @K.Uzair it is inserting in database but here i need to show the total value in the div itself once i enter the other values

Comment: @K.Uzair before submitting the data it should show the total value in the total div

Comment: when i enter abc+def+ghi the total amount value should be populated in the total div column but here it is not showing the total amount in the div

Comment: anyone who can help me these

Comment: for that you have to sum up these values in jQuery or JavaScript to do so.